# How to set relationship to object in Core Data?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I created two relationship entites. I save name into the attribute of the first entity after I move to another `UIViewController` and I save elements of array in order into the attribute of the second entity. I make that I can to see the results of saving. I see that each element have a relationship with the first entity. After I return to the first `UITableViewController` and move to the second `UITableViewController` which is showing elements which belong the name attribute of the first entity. I get an error here. I have only last element of the array. Other elements have not the relationship with the first entity. How can I remake it? Please show me it programmatically.

```
   let testArray = ["iMac", "Mac Pro", "MacBook Pro", "iPhone", "iPad"]
    @IBAction func saveData(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        for element in testArray {
            let personEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Person
            let carEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Car", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Car
            let object: AnyObject? = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.first
            let fixPersonEntity = object as! Person
            carEntity.personCar = element
            carEntity.personRelationship = fixPersonEntity
            println(carEntity)
            fixPersonEntity.setValue(Set(arrayLiteral: carEntity), forKey: "carRelationship")
            managedObjectContext.save(nil)
        }
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let navi = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navi") as! UINavigationController
        presentViewController(navi, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The console shows following results when I am saving the array

```
<Car: 0x1702a60c0> (entity: Car; id: 0x170229660 <x-coredata:///Car/tB81E6F91-4479-409B-AF1F-07AE75E1826F4> ; data: {
    personCar = iMac;
    personRelationship = "0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://833104DC-EFF4-412D-AFCB-186BA53725F4/Person/p1>";
})
<Car: 0x1702a2d00> (entity: Car; id: 0x17022e980 <x-coredata:///Car/tB81E6F91-4479-409B-AF1F-07AE75E1826F6> ; data: {
    personCar = "Mac Pro";
    personRelationship = "0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://833104DC-EFF4-412D-AFCB-186BA53725F4/Person/p1>";
})
<Car: 0x1742a5400> (entity: Car; id: 0x174232500 <x-coredata:///Car/tB81E6F91-4479-409B-AF1F-07AE75E1826F8> ; data: {
    personCar = "MacBook Pro";
    personRelationship = "0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://833104DC-EFF4-412D-AFCB-186BA53725F4/Person/p1>";
})
<Car: 0x1702a1fe0> (entity: Car; id: 0x170230240 <x-coredata:///Car/tB81E6F91-4479-409B-AF1F-07AE75E1826F10> ; data: {
    personCar = iPhone;
    personRelationship = "0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://833104DC-EFF4-412D-AFCB-186BA53725F4/Person/p1>";
})
<Car: 0x1702a34e0> (entity: Car; id: 0x170232720 <x-coredata:///Car/tB81E6F91-4479-409B-AF1F-07AE75E1826F12> ; data: {
    personCar = iPad;
    personRelationship = "0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://833104DC-EFF4-412D-AFCB-186BA53725F4/Person/p1>";
})
```

This is an example from the second `UITableViewController` that the object have not the relationship

```
<Car: 0x1742a5580> (entity: Car; id: 0xd0000000000c0002 <x-coredata://833104DC-EFF4-412D-AFCB-186BA53725F4/Car/p3> ; data: {
    personCar = "MacBook Pro";
    personRelationship = nil;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed code and it works for me

```
  let testArray = ["Zone", "Implicit", "Comma", "Department", "Define", "Provide"]
    @IBAction func saveData(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        for element in testArray {
            let personEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Person
            let carEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Car", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Car
            let object: AnyObject? = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.first
            var fixPersonEntity = object as! Person
            println(fixPersonEntity)
            carEntity.personCar = element
            carEntity.personRelationship = fixPersonEntity
            managedObjectContext.save(nil)
        }
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let navi = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navi") as! UINavigationController
        presentViewController(navi, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```